# Kosher food on cruises?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, food, vehicles-transportation

I will be going on a cruise. I know that some cruises have Kosher menu selections that are actually verified Kosher, not just “Jewish Style meals”. My question is that how can these be kosher without a mashgiach? I am assuming that they don’t have one, does anyone know? Also, I doubt they have a separate kitchen for kosher food, or do they? If anyone can let me know how the Kosher food on cruises work, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you assume there is no mashgiach? You ought to ask before you make assumptions. My next guess would be that the meals are similar to airline kosher meals.

Comment: I was on a cruise which had a kosher subsection with a mashgiach but I didn't pay for that so I survived on unlimited airline meals. Also, free M+M's.

Answer (score 6):

Based on our experience on three such cruises in the US and Europe (and many religious friends doing the same), there are two options. Sometimes both are on the same boat at the same time.

1. Airline-style (somewhat improved) meals which you can choose from a large selection. They come double wrapped and under supervision of a national kosher agency (e.g., [Norwegian](https://www.ncl.com) used OK in 2016-2018). In addition, the boat will often have other kosher products served and you can ask to see the *hekhsher* (classic examples: bagels, cream cheese, some ice cream, fruit).
2. A separate kitchen with a *mashgiach* who supervises food preparation the whole time and waiters/cooks trained by the *mashgiach*.

Both can be impeccably kosher but **you need to check arrangements in advance to be sure they will be there on the boat you take and make sure you are comfortable with them.**